# Scripting and Java Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, scripting

I work on a web app designed for helping transportation companies manage non-emergency trips. The server side is Jboss Web, which is a modified version of Tomcat 6. The company that I work for has recently been tasked with adding some custom functionality for specific customers.

The app is capable of importing a CSV file from a 3rd party company. The CSV contains a listing of trips that the company can import into our software and then manage the trips from there. What some of our customers have been asking for is a feature to default a scheduled pickup and scheduled drop-off time based on the appointment time in the CSV, per record. However, all of our customers have different methods of estimating these times. I'm thinking that I can achieve this custom functionality with some short scripts added per company. However, I would like to be able to have database access from the script. What I would really like is the ability to pass the existing connection object from the java servlet to the script itself. If I could do it this way then I eliminate the need to open/close a connection per record in the CSV. I wouldn't be setting any data in the database from the script itself. I would just be looking up values in the database to aid in the calculations.

So, after explaining all that, this is what I want to know. Is there scripting language out there that allows me to pass in and return native java objects from a java servlet?

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are HTTP listeners.  They require that you pass HTTP requests and responses.  These don't know or care about Java objects.  You'll have to marshall your Java objects to Strings and encode them properly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Apparently everything I wanted is built into java. Java has the ability to pass java objects into a javascript invocation and those objects can be used as if native java objects. I was able to set a global java.sql.Connection in the javascript invocation and read the database exactly as I would in java. Also, I was able to modify passed in objects and return them to the calling java code. Here is the code that worked.

The Java source file.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class JSTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JSTest().go();
    }

    public void go(){
        Connection db = null;
        try {
            //Initialize all of the built in Java script parsing classes
            ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
            db = login("127.0.0.1", "3306", "testdb", "user", "password");
            //set the database connection as a global variable for the javascript object.
            engine.put("g_connection",db);
            engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("/home/scripts/testScript.js"));
            Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;

            //Put together some sample data for the script to manipulate
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
            cal.set(2014, 6, 20, 10, 30, 0);
            Date apptTime = cal.getTime();

            TripLeg tripLeg = new TripLeg();
            tripLeg.setLegSequence("A");
            tripLeg.setAppointmentTime(apptTime);
            tripLeg.setProjectedMiles(5);
            Trip trip = new Trip();
            trip.setClientID(5);//This is the id of the client record. I need to look it up in the script.
            tripLeg = (TripLeg) inv.invokeFunction("modifyTripLeg", trip, tripLeg);

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            if (tripLeg.getScheduledPUTime() != null)
                System.out.println(format.format(tripLeg.getScheduledPUTime()));
            else
                System.out.println("PU time not set.");
            if (tripLeg.getScheduledDOTime() != null)
                System.out.println(format.format(tripLeg.getScheduledDOTime()));
            else
                System.out.println("DO time not set.");
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (db != null)
                    db.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public Connection login (String server, String port, String database, String userName, String password)
    {
        Connection  db = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", server, port, database);
            db = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);      
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return db;
    }
    //Sample trip and trip leg classes stripped down to the bare minimum stuff that I need to access.
    public class Trip{
        private  int clientID;
        public int getClientID() {
            return clientID;
        }
        public void setClientID(int clientID) {
            this.clientID = clientID;
        }
    }
    public class TripLeg{
        private Date scheduledPUTime;
        private Date scheduleDOTime;
        private Date appointmentTime;
        private String legSequence;
        private double projectedMiles;

        public Date getScheduledPUTime() {
            return scheduledPUTime;
        }
        public void setScheduledPUTime(Date scheduledPUTime) {
            this.scheduledPUTime = scheduledPUTime;
        }
        public Date getScheduledDOTime() {
            return scheduleDOTime;
        }
        public void setScheduledDOTime(Date scheduleDOTime) {
            this.scheduleDOTime = scheduleDOTime;
        }
        public Date getAppointmentTime() {
            return appointmentTime;
        }
        public void setAppointmentTime(Date appointmentTime) {
            this.appointmentTime = appointmentTime;
        }
        public String getLegSequence() {
            return legSequence;
        }
        public void setLegSequence(String legSequence) {
            this.legSequence = legSequence;
        }
        public double getProjectedMiles() {
            return projectedMiles;
        }
        public void setProjectedMiles(double projectedMiles) {
            this.projectedMiles = projectedMiles;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the javascript source file. (/home/scripts/testScript.js)

```
function modifyTrip(trip, tripLeg){
    return trip;
};
function modifyTripLeg(trip, tripLeg){
    var importFormat = getClientImportFormat(trip.getClientID());
    var legSequence = tripLeg.getLegSequence();
    var scheduledPUTime = tripLeg.getScheduledPUTime();
    var scheduledDOTime = tripLeg.getScheduledDOTime();
    var appointmentTime = tripLeg.getAppointmentTime();
    var projectedMiles = tripLeg.getProjectedMiles();

    if (importFormat == "TESTER_CLIENT"){
        if (legSequence == "A"){
            if (isEmptyDate(scheduledPUTime) && !isEmptyDate(appointmentTime) && !isEmptyDouble(projectedMiles))
                scheduledPUTime = new Date(appointmentTime.getTime() - ((projectedMiles + 45) * 60 *1000));
            if (isEmptyDate(scheduledDOTime) && !isEmptyDate(appointmentTime))
                scheduledDOTime = new Date(appointmentTime.getTime() - (15 * 60 *1000));
        }

        if (legSequence == "B"){
            if (scheduledPUTime == null && appointmentTime != null && (projectedMiles != null && projectedMiles > 0.00))
                scheduledPUTime = new Date(appointmentTime.getTime() - ((projectedMiles + 45) * 60 *1000));
            if (scheduledDOTime == null && appointmentTime != null)
                scheduledPUTime = new Date(appointmentTime.getTime() - (15 * 60 *1000));
        }
    }
    tripLeg.setScheduledPUTime(scheduledPUTime);
    tripLeg.setScheduledDOTime(scheduledDOTime);
    return tripLeg;
};
function getClientImportFormat(clientID){
    var sql = "select ImportFormat from Client where id = ?";
    var stmt = g_connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    stmt.setInt(1, clientID);
    var rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    var importFormat = "";
    if (rs.next()){
        importFormat = rs.getString(1);
    }
    rs.close();
    return importFormat;    
}
function isEmptyDate(testDate){
    if (!testDate)
        return true;
    if (testDate == null)
        return true;
    return false;
};
function isEmptyDouble(testDouble){
    if (!testDouble)
        return true;
    if (testDouble == null)
        return true;
    if (testDouble <= 0.0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The two pages that made it all clear to me:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html
http://javalandscape.blogspot.com/2008/12/scripting-in-jdk6-jsr-223-part-2.html

Also, my company is still using java 6, so the nashorn engine is not available to me. Whenever I requested the engine in code I used "javascript" instead, and for the limited things I needed to do, it worked just fine. And this all worked flawlessly from within a java servlet.

Hopefully this helps someone else that comes along looking for something similar.

Comment: I've not studied your code in detail. But I wonder **why you are using JavaScript** at all? Hopefully you know that, despite the name, JavaScript has nothing to do with Java. If you are already working in Java with your Servlets, then you can do CSV file reading, database access, and date-time work all in pure Java. Also, for doing date-time work in Java, do *not* use the bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar and SimpleDateFormat classes as they are notoriously troublesome. Use Joda-Time or the new java.time in Java 8. Bonus tip: [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com).

Comment: This is the situation. We have a web app that helps non-emergency transportation (NET) providers manage their day to day trips. There is another agency that gathers up trips and assigns them to various NET providers across the state. The big agency provides each of these NET providers with CSV files at least once per day that has all of the trips that provider is supposed to take care of.

What our customers want (NET Providers) is to be able to have some custom functionality added upon import of the CSV file. They want to be able to modify a scheduled pickup/drop-off time based on

Comment: the appointment time. This formula for setting the times is specific to each NET provider. So I needed a way to script the formula. If I can do this in pure Java, then that would be great. Any suggestions?